# JSP's <bean:message> equivalent in Java class?

Tags: java, jsp, struts, struts-1

With reference to this question - [bean:message equivalent in java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264575/beanmessage-equivalent-in-java-code#)

I have the similar question based on Struts 1.2 as well. Generally I would do this in JSP with the help of `<bean:message>` tag but this code is implemented in a Java class (`.java`). I want to internationalize the string that is referenced from a properties file (originally it isn't). How can I do it in a Java class equivalent to JSP's `<bean:message>`?

```
// Help

NestedMenu nestedMenu = new SimpleNestedMenu(  );
nestedMenu.setValue( "Help" );                  // I'd like to internationalize this string
nestedMenu.setLink( "do/oer?actionMethod=help" );
```

This is the parameter I have in `struts-config.xml`:

```
<message-resources
        parameter="com.sd.oer.properties.ApplicationResource" />
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/

Comment: Personally I'd rewrite this as a JSP-based custom JSP tag since this type of presentation work really belongs in the presentation layer. As Elliott says, normal I18N would work fine. In any case, the `message` tag uses a combination of `TagUtils#message` and normal S1 tag property lookup, but since you're just doing "plain" I18N, the normal Java stuff should work.